# How can I remove a peer and organization from BYFN?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

How can I remove peers and organizations from BYFN?
I was working on the Fabcar network to add and encountered problems with container conflicts. Anyway, to avoid future issues, I would like to know more directly which files should I change to remove BYFN peers and orgs? What do I need to change in the following files?

```
configtx.yaml
crypto-config.yaml
docker-compose.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

configtx.yaml and crypto-config.yaml are files used by tools to generate channel configuration out of defined profiles and generate crypto material based on  templates and configuration you provided in `crypto-config.yaml`.

Whereas `docker-compose.yml` defines your local network with set of peers for each organization and ordering service. Therefore if you need to add or remove something you need to edit this file.